# Conditional Formula formatting in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email, formula

I am wondering if there is a way to set conditional formulas in Visualforce templates where fields that have a NULL value do not appear as empty spaces in the template.

For instance I have a field "In_Honor_Of__c" if this field is null in record it should not display the null value, or extra space, at all.

Let me know if you have any questions and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps wrapping that section in an `apex:outputPanel`.. [Doc Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm)

e.g.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!ISBLANK(YOUR_OBJECT.In_Honor_Of__c)}">
    // desired markup here
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Any reason why an outputPanel can't be used? Hope this helps!